# Touchpad gesture available in Unity?

Tags: 12.10, touchpad, multi-touch

By default, my touchpad support two finger scrolling, two finger tap to double click, and single tap on upper right corner of touchpad to middle click (which is annoying, accidentally do middle click most of the time).

Can I change the middle click to three finger tap and get pinch to zoom my touchpad?

I have standard Synaptic Touchpad, **fully supported** and all gesture are available on Windows with Synaptic Touchpad Driver.

I don't want `easystroke`, I need to configure tap, not stroke, and `easystroke` doesn't work anyway, I can record stroke, but never be able to draw the stroke to run my preferred action.

Answer (score 0):

you may take a look at touchegg : http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43097/how-to-get-macbook-style-finger-gestures-on-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: While the link might answer the question, is preferable if you include the specific steps from it and just include the link as reference.